# Pytest: Using same variable for multiple tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, flask, pytest

I'm currently working on a Flask app and unit testing with pytest. I'm still new to Python class structures, flask and testing.

Please refer to sample code below:

```
from somewhere import search_person

class TestMethodOne:

    def test_method_with_x(self):
        person = { 
            "first_name": "John", 
            "last_name": "Smith", 
            "state": "CA" 
        }
        assert search_person(person) is not None
        

    def test_method_with_y(self):
        person = { 
            "first_name": "John", 
            "last_name": "Smith", 
            "state": "CA" 
        }
        assert search_person(person)["full_name"] == "John M Smith"
```

The search_person method utilizes a third party API and takes some time to run, I wish to DRY this so that the test does not make redundant calls. Is there a way I can set this up so the search_person(person) has already been called once pytest creates this class and all the test methods will just reference that variable?

Comment: Declare the variable inside the class like `self.person = `

Comment: @Hedy and then the test run in an other order and fail.

Comment: Test should be self-contained. That means every test should run on it's own independent of others. If you want to test multiple things for the same call, you should put them into one test. BTW in the case you presented here, the first `assert` statement is covered by the second.

Comment: @KlausD. I understand that in principle, but it seems inefficient to run the function multiple times with the same data. The third party API takes ~10 seconds to complete. Especially since majority of tests will work with this API, if I don't find ways to reduce the API calls, testing is going to take forever to finish running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the pytest fixtures feature:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session

> Fixtures requiring network access depend on connectivity and are usually time-expensive to create. .... we can add a scope="module" parameter to the @pytest.fixture invocation to cause the decorated smtp_connection fixture function to only be invoked once per test module (the default is to invoke once per test function). **Multiple test functions in a test module will thus each receive the same smtp_connection fixture instance, thus saving time.** Possible values for scope are: function, **class**, module, package or session.